# How to create an IEnumerable with optional Action?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have `IntegerRectangle` class. I want it to have an `internal_perimeter()` method which returns all points of its perimeter and `internal_perimeter(Action<Integer> processor)` which applies `processor` to all points of its perimeter.

One of my classes has a variable `IntegerRect canvas;` and `HashSet<IntegerPoint> forbidden_points` It calls:

```
canvas.internal_perimeter((IntegerPoint p)=>{forbidden_points.Add(p); print("[f]" + forbidden_points.Contains(p).ToString());});
```

The result differs between different implementations of `internal_perimeter()`

This works:

```
public IEnumerable<IntegerPoint> internal_perimeter()
{
    for(int i=0;i<width;++i)
    {
        yield return new IntegerPoint(x+i,y);
    }
    for(int i=1;i<height;++i)
    {
        yield return new IntegerPoint(x+width-1,y-i);
    }
    for(int i=width-2;i>=0;--i)
    {
        yield return new IntegerPoint(x+i,y-height+1);
    }
    for(int i=height-2;i>=0;--i)
    {
        yield return new IntegerPoint(x,y-i);
    }
}
public void internal_perimeter(Action<IntegerPoint> processor)
{
    foreach(IntegerPoint i in internal_perimeter())
        processor(i);
}
```

This doesn't:

```
public IEnumerable<IntegerPoint> internal_perimeter(Action<IntegerPoint> processor=null)
{
    if(processor==null)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<width;++i)
        {
            yield return new IntegerPoint(x+i,y);
        }
        for(int i=1;i<height;++i)
        {
            yield return new IntegerPoint(x+width-1,y-i);
        }
        for(int i=width-2;i>=0;--i)
        {
            yield return new IntegerPoint(x+i,y-height+1);
        }
        for(int i=height-2;i>=0;--i)
        {
            yield return new IntegerPoint(x,y-i);
        }
    }
    else
        foreach(IntegerPoint i in internal_perimeter())
            processor(i);
}
```

I don't understand what is wrong with the second one

Comment: This is a bad way to structure your code. Why would you want to put the overload that takes an `Action` inside that class? If some external code needs to do something, it can `foreach` on its own.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Do they work the same when you do not pass a processor?

Comment: @Jon Because this way I can write foreach only once.

Comment: @user2136963: the second, overloaded method doesn't belong in this class at all (and it's really poorly named).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight When I call `canvas.internal_perimeter((IntegerPoint p)=>{forbidden_points.Add(p); print("[f]" + forbidden_points.Contains(p).ToString());});`

Comment: What happens when you make this call? Is there a crash? Do you see any actions being called? My guess is that when you make that call, nothing happens, right? You should say this in the body of the question, rather than having us to take a guess. Anyway, you've got a good answer here!

Comment: @user2136963: Minimizing duplication is good enough that it can trump other considerations. Minimizing *keystrokes* is barely good enough to stand as an argument on its own -- and when it starts running into other problems, the argument falls apart. You might want to write some other method (e.g. an extension method) to do this, but using a second overload of `internal_perimeter` is just bad.

Comment: @Jon You have a point. I'll switch the name for the second function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second example is an iterator (ie it uses `yield return`). This kind of function is not executed until you enumerate it.

If you do: `var x = internal_perimeter(i => {});`
The variable `x` will hold an `IEnumerable<IntegerPoint>` of a class constructed by the compiler from your function. Your code is not executed yet at this point.

Now, try to consume it: `foreach(var point in x) {}`. This will execute your function. Actually in your particular case, it will all be executed on the first iteration, so calling `x.FirstOrDefault();` will be enough. Indeed, calling `MoveNext` on the enumerator will execute the code up to the first `yield return`, and there are none in the `else` branch of your code.

Now, I'd go with your first example because of this. It is less error prone.

Answer (score 3):

To add to [@Lucas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25382622/69809), which answers why your code doesn't work, you should also consider refactoring your code:

1. `internal_perimeter` is a bad name for the method. If its purpose is to mutate internal points, then it should be named `void Process(Action a)` or something like that.
2. The second example is rather problematic because it returns *nothing* (an empty sequence) when you don't pass `null` for the action parameter. It would make more sense to use a `Func<T, Tresult` (like LINQ Select) and yield return all processed parameters. Also, the `null` branch is really uncommon (it is rarely recommended to pass a `null` delegate like this).
3. Next, the method really does too little. Why do you need a new method which has an existing LINQ alternative? I.e.:

   ```
   var rect = new IntegerRectangle();

   // this gets a list of points
   var forbiddenPoints = rect.internal_perimeter().ToList();

   // this filters them and projects them 
   // (i.e. "get all x coordinates larger then 10")
   var xLargerThan10 = rect
      .internal_perimeter()
      .Where(p => p.X > 10)
      .Select(p => p.X)
      .ToList();
   ```
4. Even the original `internal_perimeter` overload might have a better name, e.g. simply `GetPoints` would be pretty indicative of what its purpose is:

   ```
   foreach (var point in rect.GetPoints())
       DoStuff(point);
   ```

Comment: Didn't know about LINQ. I named it `internal_perimeter` because I needed to distinguish between `internal_perimeter()`, `external_perimeter()` and `all_points()`.